# Java tzupdater + IANA trouble in ubuntu

Tags: java, timezone, tomcat7, iana

Trying to update Java timezone on 2 computers (Brazil no longer observes DST).
Windows worked fine, but I'm having some trouble in Ubuntu.

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded Most recent timezone (**tzdata2019c**): https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2019c.tar.gz
2. Downloaded **tzupdater**: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html
3. Run: **java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -f -l file:tzdata2019c.tar.gz**

On Windows it worked fine.
On Ubuntu, this is the output:

**sudo java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -f -l file:tzdata2019c.tar.gz**

```
Using file:tzdata2019c.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
java.vendor: Private Build
java.version: 1.8.0_222
tzupdater version 2.3.0-b01
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2019a
Downloaded file to /tmp/tz.tmp_1/tzdata.tar.gz
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:705)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:237)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:686)
```

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Used ZI updater and worked fine:
https://www.azul.com/products/open-source-tools/ziupdater-time-zone-tool/